# Разбить логическую цепочку or на отдельные строки (Ansible)

Tags: ansible, yaml

Добрый вечер.

Как разбить очень длинную цепочку из or на строки для удобства чтения?

```
- degub:
    msg: "Сообщить если одно из условий выполнено"
  when: long_variable_name != none or long_variable_name in check_list or long_variable_name in check_list_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. плейбуки написаны на YAML, можно использовать все его свойства. В т.ч. и [переносы строк](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/2795592):

```
- debug:
    msg: "Сообщить если одно из условий выполнено"
  when: >
        long_variable_name != none
        or long_variable_name in check_list
        or long_variable_name in check_list_2
```